# How do we call Power Automate Flow using Javascript button click?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, power-automate

we have a requirement of triggering the power automate flow using javascript button, we are still using the classic sharepoint site, we need to pass an item id to the power automate if they select an item in the list view and click on the button.

On the power automate side we will fetch the item by id and try to perform some calculations and update a different list.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/trigger-a-microsoft-flow-with-a-button-click-on-sharepoint-online/) if it helps you somehow.

Answer (score 1):

You can design a flow that is triggered by [HTTP-request](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-reqres). Just describe the schema of the request body and pass any parameters in the body of the post-request as demonstrated here:

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/call-flow-restapi/